# Register and Log in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Hi i am trying a simple app with registration and when is complete , go to home view , but when i try to go HomeView my app crashes

this is the code

```
@IBAction func Registrar(sender: AnyObject) {

        let userName = UserName.text!
        let userEmail = UserEmail.text!
        let medicRegistry = MedicRegistry.text!
        let specialty = Speciality.text!
        let country = Country.text!
        let city = Ciudad.text!
        let userPass = UserPassword.text!
        let repeatPass = RepeatPassword.text!



        if ( userName.isEmpty || userEmail.isEmpty || medicRegistry.isEmpty || speciality.isEmpty || country.isEmpty || city.isEmpty || userPass.isEmpty || userEmail.isEmpty ) {

            let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Sign Up Failed!"
            alertView.message = "Por favor llene todos los campos"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()
        } else if ( userPass != repeatPass)  {

            let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Sign Up Failed!"
            alertView.message = "Passwords doesn't Match"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()

           //NSUserDefaults.standarUserDefaults().setObject(id, forKey:"userId")
            //NSUserDefaults.standarUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }else if check == false{
            let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Fallo al Registrar!"
            alertView.message = "Debes aceptar los terminos y condiciones"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()


        }

        else {

            let url_servicio = "http://mydirection.php"

                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url_servicio)!)
                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "nombre=\(userName)&email=\(userEmail)&registro=\(medicRegistry)&esp=\(specialty)&pais=\(country)&ciudad=\(city)&contrasena=\(userPass)"
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error -> Void in
                if (error != nil){
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }else{
                    let nsdata:NSData = NSData(data: data!)

                    do{
                        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nsdata, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                        let Id = json["id"] as! String
                        let c: String = ""


                        if (Id != c){
                            print (Id)
                 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("funciona", sender: self)
                        }
                    }
                    catch{
                        print("Error del JSON")

                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()

                   }
        }
}
```

[image: Error]
i manage to print the Id but when then just crash
i am new in this and i dont know whats wrong
thx for ur help.

[image]

Comment: What is your error log?? Where are you getting error?

Comment: So you can print the id? That means that up to the print (Id) estalog = true line everything works. Maybe the error is in your segue. Did you remember to set the "funciona" identifier in your segue?

Comment: do you have a segue called `funciona` in storyboard?

Comment: yes i have a segue called funciona , there is a screenshot of the xcode logs

Comment: Please edit with complete error log.its showing partial, we cant scroll bro

Comment: can you scroll up the xcode logs and show us the error?

Comment: ho yeah sorry , and thx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the error message: "Only run on the main thread".

Your completion handler runs in the background but is trying to change the UI using a segue.  You should dispatch your `performSegueWithIdentifier` back to the main thread.

Comment: u mean use "self.dismissViewControllerAnimatedself.dismissViewControllerAnimated" ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I didn't say anything about "dismiss".

Comment: haha sorry , first thanks for the help , i am new in swift lenguage , can u explain where is the error in my code if u have time of course plz

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `Alamofire`. The function `dataTaskWithRequest` seems not run in main thread and causes conflicts.

If you don't want change to `Alamofire`. So use this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    //here your segue
 })
```

Comment: indeed , i begin to investigate about dispatch  with  Phillip Mills ansewer , but thank for share the info about alamofire , i will read about it when i can  , & tyvm

Comment: @elkin sepulveda, This answer It is exactly what Phillip Mills means. You send in the main thread is done with the code I left you.